# Get number of Google+ counts / shares using 'get' method via Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-plus

How can I get the number of Google+ counts via JavaScript (as an integer number) using "get"?

In twitter For example , we can get that using the URL:
[http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url='+](http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=%27+) url

For Google+ shares, I found that we can get the whole g+ icon and the number of shares using
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url= url

Also, I found a way to get number of G+ counts by making AJAX request

How can I get it as a digit value via "get".

Answer (score 0):

I will strongly recommend against using raw API queries like you are doing. Generate a simple API key with access to the Google+ API on the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

You can find the post from a given URL and get the activity details as follows, note that I'm using the [Google API client for JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/):

```
/**
 * Performs the API queries for searching,
 *
 * @param {String} searchUrl The Url containing the user ID for searching.
 * @param {int} queryCount The number of API calls made.
 * @param {String} nextPageToken The next page token for paged api calls.
 */
function searchForUrl(searchUrl, queryCount, nextPageToken){
  var userId = searchUrl.split('/')[3];

  gapi.client.plus.activities.list({userId: userId,
      pageToken: nextPageToken}).execute( function(resp){
        handleActivities(resp.items, searchUrl, queryCount, resp.nextPageToken);
      });
}


/**
 * Parses and stores activities from the XMLHttpRequest
 *
 * @param {Object} activities The response activity objects as an array.
 * @param {String} postUrl The URL of the post.
 * @param {int} queryCount The number of API calls.
 * @param {string} nextPageToken The next page token.
 */
function handleActivities(activities, postUrl, queryCount, nextPageToken){
  for (var activity in activities){
    activity = activities[activity];
    if (activity['url'] == postUrl){
      targetActivity = activity;
      document.getElementById('result').value = 'ID is: ' +
          activity.id + '\n' +
          'PlusCount is: ' + activity.object.plusoners.totalItems + '\n' +
          'Replies are: ' + activity.object.replies.totalItems + '\n' +
          'Reshares are: ' + activity.object.resharers.totalItems + '\n';
      isFound = true;
    }else{
      console.log(activity);
    }
  }

  if (queryCount < maxQueryCount && !isFound){
    queryCount++;

    // throttle calls using timer to avoid reaching query limit
    console.log('retrying with ' + nextPageToken);
    setTimeout(searchForUrl(postUrl, queryCount, nextPageToken), 100);
  }
}
```

Demo at http://wheresgus.com/urltoid/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it's very helpful, however, I am actually looking for a way to provide a URL instead of a userid in order to return the share counts, is it possible to query gapi and return a link share counts?

Comment: Yes, you can do this as well, but it's a bit tricky.... Check the code here: http://wheresgus.com/urltoid/ I'll update my answer when I get the chance.